# Сравнение элементов массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть задача проверить два массива - server и site. В каждом из массивов только уникальные элементы (нет дублей). Мне необходимо сравнить массивы по следующей логике:

- если в массиве server есть элемент, а в массиве site нет - запустить ф-ию add().
- если и в массиве server и в массиве site есть одинаковый элемент - запустить ф-ию update().
- если в массиве server нет элемента, а в массиве site есть - запустить ф-ию remove().

Важно - я могу пользоваться ограниченными методами, т.к. работаю в так называемой serverSide JS.  Так, для прохода для массива и могу использовать конструкцию `for(x in y){}` или `for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){}`

Вот таким образом я решил эту задачу:

```
server = ['1', '2', '3']
site = ['0', '1', '2']

function add(elem) {
    alert('добавляем ' + elem)
}

function update(elem) {
    alert('обновляем ' + elem)  
}

function remove(elem) {
    alert('удаляем ' + elem)  
}


for (elemServ in server) {
    addElem = true
    for (elemSite in site) {
        if (elemServ == elemSite) {
            update(elemSite)
            addElem = false
            break;
        }
    }
    if (addElem) {
        add(elemServ)
    }
}

for (elemSite in site) {
    removeElem = true
    for (elemServ in server) {
        if (elemSite == elemServ) {
            removeElem = false
        }
    }
    if (removeElem) {
        remove(elemSite)
    }
}
```

Вопрос: есть какой-либо более элегантный способ решить данную задачу?

Comment: Мап\сет можно использовать?

Comment: Нет, только цикл For, while, return работает )

Comment: Массивы случайно не сортированные? Если нет - нельзя отсортировать?

Comment: нет. На самом деле элемент массива - это код элемента. Он может быть любого вида.

Comment: for in это цикл по объекту, а не по массиву